# Best Way to store and render Unicode Emojis in Android

Tags: android, unicode, emoji

i have a simple Memory Game as Project. For the Memory Tiles I wanted to use Emojis. I tried to use it that way:

```
emojiCard.setText(new String(Character.toChars(Integer.parseInt(1F60D, 16))));
```

now I just have to save **1F60D** to a variable and can show the emoji.

that works for simple emojis but I cannot use the "new" ones because then i have to use surrogate pairs and I don't know how to do this.

Is there a better way ? like saving the unicode ?

sorry i'am really new to android development and tried already a lot of things.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Integer.parseInt()` takes a `String` as input, so presumably you meant to say `Integer.parseInt("1F60D", 16)` instead. Which would be wasted overhead when you can simply pass a numeric `0x1F60D` literal to `Character.toChars()` instead.

Java strings use UTF-16 encoding. When encoded to UTF-16, codepoint U+1F60D uses surrogate pairs, so surrogates is not your issue.

Assuming you are referring to how newer emojis support modifiers (to change their genders, colors, etc), then that has nothing to do with surrogates. You simply append the modifier codepoint(s) you want after the base emoji codepoint. For example:

```
emojiCard.setText(new String(Character.toChars(0x1F466)) + new String(Character.toChars(0x1F3FE)));
```

( +  = )